# wildlfy 16 - UT010053: No confidential port is available to redirect the current request

Tags: soap, undertow

My setup: A https loadbalancer with http wildflynodes running in domain mode
Entry to the application by https loadbalancer to application nodes : 443 to 8080 & 8180 - application forwarding works, and all functions are usable of the application.

The problem appears only for SOAP-Webservice.

The wsdl is accessible under https//loadbalancerurl:443/.. and the problem comes by accessing the webservice methods.

The problem seems to be forwarding from 443 to confidential port 8443 - the error message is when the access from client to the SOAP-webservice happens:

> UT010053: No confidential port is available to redirect the current request.

I know that this comes from Undertow-Servlet from here:

```
protected URI getRedirectURI(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws URISyntaxException {
        int port = portManager.getConfidentialPort(exchange);
        if (port < 0) {
            throw MESSAGES.noConfidentialPortAvailable();
        }

        return super.getRedirectURI(exchange, port);
    }
```

So port is < 0.

So the question is how to achieve for Undertow that confidentialport will be delivered = is configured in the right way ?

My domain xml contains:

```
<server name="default-server">
                    <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"   certificate-forwarding="true" proxy-address-forwarding="true" />
                    
                  
                </server>
<socket-binding-group name="pze4-sockets" default-interface="public">
            <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
            <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
            <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
            <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
```

In the application jboss-webservices.xml Confidential is configured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<webservices xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <port-component>
        <ejb-name>MyWebservice</ejb-name>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </port-component>
</webservices>
```

The same setup of loadbalancer and wildfly-nodes had worked for Wildfly8 for the SOAP Webservice.

My tries so far:

Adding the https-listener did not help:

```
  <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
```

The hint from did not work too:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/270026

Adding the SSL-cetrifacate to java on the nodes did not help too.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was too facing the same issue and it was due to the configurations in my `web.xml` file. had something like  ```<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing  redirect-socket attribute in http-listener it solved my problem
see here : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow